# Notify to Admin web portal (Sync through Notification/Other) - PHP

Tags: php, node.js, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Problem:**

- I have Admin web portal which builds on PHP (CodeIgniter). which I want to make Sync Immediately while there is some change in Database.

**Confusion :**

- As far as I tried to check from Google to solve the problem, there are two way I found

  1. Push notification for notifying to web portal on change of database
  2. Long Pooling which continuously listen to change and sends to the web portal.

**Backend Database:**  MySql

Kindly please help me to get Best Practice for it. and also suggest more option if available.